# How to create a makefile to call a buildscript?

Tags: makefile

Hi I have a build script called "buildMyJava" that builds a bunch of Java source code. Assuming those source code are in differnet directories such as "folder1" and "folder2", the output goes to some folder called "classes". How do I create a makefile so it KNOWS to build only when the source code meaning the *.java in those two directories have changed as well as the output classes is missing?

I have something like the following but it ALWAYS builds, dependencies are not working.

```
all: task

task: folder1/*.java folder2/*.java classes/
    buildMyJava
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the build script produces the .java files, thus the .java files should be targets, not prerequisites.  So you should have something like this:

```
folder1/%.java folder2/%.java: 
    buildMyJava
```

The only problem with this is that if you do a make -j2, buildMyJava will run multiple times (once for folder1, and once for folder2).   In fact, this is a limitation to makefiles -- you cannot have multiple targets invoke the same recipe only once.  There is a good discussion on this here: http://www.cmcrossroads.com/article/rules-multiple-outputs-gnu-make

Notice though that a 'pattern' target counts as a single target though -- which means, if you can get a pattern to match all targets, you can invoke the recipe only once.  A small caveat to that -- the `%` symbol cannot represent `/`'s.  Thus you cannot do `folder%.java`, as that would not match `folder1/file1.java`...   If you can split your script to output only to one directory at a time though, you may be able to do the following:

```
folder1/%.java:
    buildMyJava folder1

folder2/%.java:
    buildMyJava folder2
```

John